# Deriving conditional independence from product rule of probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

I am reading Mathematics for Machine Learning and, in the [Summary Statistics and Independence](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf#section.6.4) section, the author derives the conditional independence of two random variables given a third RV using the product rule of probability $ p(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}) = p(\boldsymbol{y}\vert\boldsymbol{x})p(\boldsymbol{x})$ (Eq 6.22) as follow

[image]

Now, I don't understand how the author derives Equation 6.56 from the product rule of probability (Eq 6.22).

Can someone please show me the full derivation and explain the intuition (if any) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional probability formulas:
$$\begin{align}p(x,y|z)=\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(z)}=\frac{p(x|y,z)p(y,z)}{p(z)}=\frac{p(x|y,z)p(y|z)p(z)}{p(z)}=p(x|y,z)p(y|z)\end{align}$$

Intuitively, the product rule still holds when we add any number of RVs to the given sides of *each* product term in both LHS and RHS.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!