Does Independence Imply Conditional Independence in regression?
I am reading The Elements of Statistical Learning (page 44) and came across this statement:

"From a statistical point of view, this criterion is reasonable if the training observations $(x_i, y_i)$ represent independent random draws from their population. Even if the $x_i$’s were not drawn randomly, the criterion is still valid if the $y_i$’s are conditionally independent given the inputs $x_i$."

To explore this, I considered the joint likelihood in two scenarios:

Case 1: Full Independence of $(x_i, y_i)$
If the $(x_i, y_i)$ pairs are fully independent, the joint likelihood is:
$$
   P(x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i \mid x_i, \theta) P(x_i \mid \theta).
   $$

Case 2: Conditional Independence of $y_i$ Given $x_i$
If the $y_i$’s are conditionally independent given $x_i$, the joint likelihood is:
$$
   P(x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n \mid \theta) = \left( \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i \mid x_i, \theta) \right) P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \mid \theta).
   $$



Observations:

Marginals:
In Case 1, the marginal distribution of the inputs factorizes as $\prod_{i=1}^n P(x_i \mid \theta)$ due to the independence assumption.
In Case 2, the marginal distribution of the inputs is written as a single term $P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \mid \theta)$ since no independence is assumed for $x_i$.

Conditionals:
In both cases, factoring out the marginals, the conditional distribution of $y_i$ given $x_i$ is identical:
$$
  \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i \mid x_i, \theta).
  $$


This suggests that the structure of the conditionals does not differ, even though the assumptions about the marginals differ.

Questions:

Are the equations for the joint likelihood in both cases accurate, and do they correctly reflect the respective independence or conditional independence assumptions?

If so, does the assumption of full independence of $(x_i, y_i)$ (Case 1) imply the conditional independence of $y_i$ given $x_i$ as shown in observations?



You seem to be implicitly assuming the $x_i$ are independent of $\theta$.  If the $x_i$ are independent of each other as implied by the $(x_i,y_i)$ being independent of each other, then yes, since that means $\prod P(x_i) = P(x_1,x_2, \ldots x_n)$

@Henry I made that assumption since for discriminative models like regression we only need to estimate conditional distribution.

Neither likelihood expression looks correct.  Consider expanding both out, in full detail, for the case $n=2,$ which involves four random variables $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2.$  You do not have to reference $\theta$ in your notation for this purpose, because the question only concerns a single distribution (cc @Henry).

Doesn't https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436525 answer your question?  You might also find https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116355 useful.

Here is a Meta.CV discussion about the answers to this question.

A pedantic note about "Even if the $x_i$’s were not drawn randomly, the criterion is still valid if the $y_i$’s are conditionally independent given the inputs $x_i$." ... if the $x_i$ are not random, then we often do not speak about 'conditional' probability. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657840

Consider a single underlying probability space with a measure $\mu_\theta$ that governs all possible realizations of $(X_i, Y_i)_{i=1}^n$. Full independence of each pair $(X_i, Y_i)$ means that for any measurable sets $A_i \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ and $B_i \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$, the measure satisfies:
$$
\mu_\theta\Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n (A_i \times B_i)\Bigr) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mu_\theta\bigl(A_i \times B_i\bigr)
$$
From the chain rule applied to each factor $P(x_i,y_i\mid\theta)$, one obtains:
$$
P(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n\mid\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i\mid x_i,\theta)P(x_i\mid\theta)
$$
Conditional independence of $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ given $X_1,\dots,X_n$ requires that for almost every configuration of $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the conditional distribution factorizes as:
$$
P(y_1,\dots,y_n\mid x_1,\dots,x_n,\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i\mid x_i,\theta)
$$
This imposes no factorization on $P(x_1,\dots,x_n\mid\theta)$, so the joint distribution becomes:
$$
P(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n\mid\theta) = \Bigl[\prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i\mid x_i,\theta)\Bigr] P(x_1,\dots,x_n\mid\theta)
$$
These factorizations match exactly the two scenarios discussed: full independence treats $(X_i,Y_i)$ as mutually independent pairs, while conditional independence concerns only the conditional structure of $Y_i$ given $X_i$. The former implies the latter, because if each pair is mutually independent, then:
$$
P(x_i,y_i\mid\theta) = P(y_i\mid x_i,\theta)P(x_i\mid \theta)
$$
and the product over all $i$ yields:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n P(x_i,y_i\mid\theta) = \Bigl[\prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i\mid x_i,\theta)\Bigr]\Bigl[\prod_{i=1}^n P(x_i\mid\theta)\Bigr]
$$
which directly recovers the conditional factorization of the outputs.
We can also view this from the perspective of filtrations and martingale theory. Define two filtrations:
$$
\mathcal{F}_k = \sigma\bigl((X_1,Y_1),\dots,(X_k,Y_k)\bigr), \quad \mathcal{G}_k = \sigma\bigl(X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_k\bigr)
$$
In both independence regimes, one can show that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_k\mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_k\mid X_k], \quad \mathbb{E}[Y_k\mid \mathcal{G}_{k-1}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_k\mid X_k]
$$
Hence both full independence and conditional independence imply that the sequence:
$$
M_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \bigl(Y_i - \mathbb{E}[Y_i\mid X_i]\bigr)
$$
is a martingale with respect to its respective filtration. The difference emerges in the variability of this martingale: under full independence,
$$
\langle M\rangle_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{Var}(Y_i\mid X_i)
$$
whereas conditional independence allows:
$$
\langle M\rangle_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{Var}(Y_i\mid X_i,\{X_j\}_{j\neq i})
$$
which reduces to the same sum as above if and only if:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(Y_i\mid X_i) = \mathrm{Var}(Y_i\mid X_i,\{X_j\}_{j\neq i})
$$
Full independence guarantees that no additional knowledge of other $(X_j,Y_j)$ can further reduce $\mathrm{Var}(Y_i\mid X_i)$. Under mere conditional independence, the first-order (martingale) structure is preserved but higher-order moment relationships may differ, revealing potential correlations among the residuals. Letting:
$$
\eta_k = Y_k - \mathbb{E}[Y_k\mid X_k]
$$
yields a sequence of martingale differences under both structures, yet full independence enforces:
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(\eta_i,\eta_j\mid X_i,X_j)=0 \quad (i\neq j)
$$
whereas conditional independence alone does not. The innovation process $\{\eta_k\}$ thus remains uncorrelated across $i,j$ only in the fully independent regime.

In the case of independent pairs

if the training observations $(x_i,y_i)$
represent independent random draws

then for a specific $k$, the distribution of $y_k,x_k$ is independent from the other $y_i$ and $x_i$. Conditioning on the other $x_i$ doesn't change anything about that.
You get that in both cases the distribution is just a product of individual terms
Unconditional
$$f(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}) = \prod_i f_i(y_i,x_i) = \prod_i g_i(y_i|x_i) h_i(x_i)$$
Conditional
$$f(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}) = \frac{f(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})}{h(\mathbf{x})} = \frac{ \prod_i f_i(y_i,x_i)}{\prod_i h_i(x)} = \prod_i g_i(y_i|x_i)$$

In terms of your cases
For iid $x_i$ we have
$$P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(x_i \mid \theta)$$
and the case 1 can always be written in the form of case 2.

More generally
A way how conditioning can change independence of $y_i$ into dependence of the $y_i$ is when the condition $x_i$ is not independent of the $y_k,x_k$ with $k\neq i$. Collider bias is an example (see also here: Can spurious correlations exist in the (theoretical) population?).

Thank you. Could you please clarify the answers to both of my questions?

If you don’t mind, could you add your answers to both the questions in my post explicitly to your answer? I’m happy to accept your answer and give the bounty post that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Could you please explicitly answer my two questions? I still cannot figure out based on your existing answer unfortunately.
